# Wordpress Dynamically Inserting Post Name as Link Text

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code in my template file to display an audio player with Download Button (download button handled by the audio player plugin)

I need the Post Name To be inserted into the code so that the resulting downloaded filename will match the post name.

example - Post Name = "Really Cool Audio" would = Really Cool Audio.mp3 when Downloaded

It also appears that spaces are being removed even though spaces in .mp3 files are "ok" and preferred.

`<?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("audio");
if (isset($customField[0])) {
echo '<h3><a href="'.$customField[0].'" class="button">Need Post Name Here</a></h3>';
} ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in The Loop (and it sounds like you are), the following should work. "Need Post Name Here" has been replaced by `.get_the_title().`

```
<?php
  $customField = get_post_custom_values("audio");
  if (isset($customField[0])) {
    echo '<h3><a href="'.$customField[0].'" class="button">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: I replaced Need Post Name Here with `<?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("audio");
if (isset($customField[0])) {
echo '<h3><a href="'.$customField[0].'" class="button">.get_the_title();</a></h3>';
} ?>`  Sorry for not understanding.  Where do I use `.get_the_title();.` ?

Comment: You need to wrap .get_the_title() in single quotes - '.get_the_title().'

Comment: Sweet!  This works!!  It removed the spaces Would it be possible to keep spaces?

Comment: It's usually better not to have spaces in file names.  The get_the_title() function includes spaces but the audio plugin probably strips them out.

Comment: I would like to leave spaces and dashes as you would see when you buy a track from iTunes  I have started another thread here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821989/wordpress-filename-same-as-post-name-keep-spaces-and-dashes)