# Wordpress filename same as Post name - Keep Spaces and dashes

Tags: wordpress

I have it set so that the filnename matches the post title using the following code.

As of right now all spaces and dashes are stripped out.

example - "Post Title 2012-2013"  becomes "PostTitle20122013.mp3"

I would like to maintain spaces and dashes in the filename.

Files are all .mp3.  As when you purchase music from iTunes spaces and dashes are "OK" and preferred.

can anyone help me with the code to allow this?

Here is my current code that is place in the loop...

`<?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("audio");
if (isset($customField[0])) {
echo '<h3><a href="'.$customField[0].'" class="button">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the dashes are being stripped out, but you can try this to keep the spaces

```
<?php
$post_title = urlencode(get_the_title());
$customField = get_post_custom_values("audio");
if (isset($customField[0])) {
 echo '<h3><a href="'.$customField[0].'" class="button">'.$post_title.'</a></h3>';
}
?>
```

Comment: it is still stripping out spaces and dashes.  can't pin down the reason why

Comment: Sounds like whatever plugin you're using is stripping everything out.  You will need to focus on that.